# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in interceptor

Tags: angular

when i deployed my project i am getting error of this. Cannot read property 'length' of null .Actually i am not getting where is the problem in my code. i share my interceptor.service code.please look it this code and share to suggestion me.where is the problem and i am sharing error screenshot also.thank you
**interceptor.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpInterceptor,HttpHandler,HttpRequest,HttpEvent,HttpClient,HttpHeaders,HttpResponse,HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';
import { LogserService } from '../logser.service';

import { Router  } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import { BatchService } from '../pages/config/batchnew/batch.service';




@Injectable()
export class MainInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    public error:boolean = true;
    constructor(public localStorage:LocalStorageService,
        public router:Router,public http:HttpClient,
        public loginService:LogserService,
      public BatchServ:BatchService
    ){

    }
//@Inject(Window) private window: any

  intercept(req:HttpRequest<any>,next:HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // console.log("interceptor",req)
    this.error=true;
    let url:any = req.url
    url = url.split('/')
    url =url[url.length-1]
    // console.log('url',url)
    // console.log(localStorage.get("token"))
    if (url =="authenticateuser"){
        const request = req.clone({
            headers:new HttpHeaders({
                // 'VitalAuthorization':  window.localStorage.getItem('token')
            })
        })
        // console.log("interceptorHeaderLogin",request)
        return  next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        // do stuff with response if you want
                        console.log("getting 39")
              }
            }, (err: any) => {
              if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                  // redirect to the login route
                            // or show a modal
                            console.log("getting 46")

                  alert('UnAutorized access');
                  // console.log(err)
                }
              }
            });
    }else{
            console.log("Line 51")
        const request = req.clone({
            headers:new HttpHeaders({
                        'Authorization':  window.localStorage.getItem('token')

            })
            })

        // console.log("interceptorHeader",request)
        return  next.handle(request).do((event: any) => {
            console.log("getting in interseptor")
}, (err: any) => {
                console.log('error401')
                // console.log('interceptorStatus',err.statusCode)
              if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status == 501) {
                  // redirect to the login route
                  // or show a modal
                            console.log('error72')
                  if( this.error===true){
                        this.error=false;
                        // this.router.navigate(['/login/'+this.localStorage.get('url')])
                        alert('Session expired ...');
                        let data = JSON.parse(this.localStorage.get('userData'))
                        this.BatchServ.createLogin(data).subscribe((data:any) => {
                            if (data.validAuthentication && data.validAuthentication != "" && data.validAuthentication != "null" && data.validAuthentication !="false"){
                                             window.localStorage.setItem('token',data.validAuthentication);
                                             console.log("line83")
                                console.log(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
                                window.location.reload();
                                         }
                                         else{

                                         }
                                     });



                  }
                  console.log(err)
                }
              }
            });

    }

    }

   }
```

and below my screen shot

[image]

Comment: `let url:any = req.url; url = url.split('/')`

can you share your service url?

Comment: yeah it is service url here--   getUrl () {
    console.log('getting')
    this.http.get('assets/api_urls.json').subscribe((res) => {
        // console.log("inUrl")
         // return (res);
         this.Api_urls= res;
         // console.log('newUrls',this.Api_urls)

       },(error)=>{
         // this.spinner.hide()
         // alert("Network Error")
         
       });    
  }

Comment: can you explain why you are splitting your url?

Comment: try to use this in your if condition.

`if(url.includes("authenticateuser")){};`

and remove this code 

url = url.split('/');
 url =url[url.length-1]

give it a try and check.

Comment: if(url.includes("authenticateuser")){}; where i put this one?

Comment: can i remove this one also  if (url =="authenticateuser"){}

Comment: `url = url.split('/')
    url =url[url.length-1]
    // console.log('url',url)
    // console.log(localStorage.get("token"))
    if (url =="authenticateuser"){`

replace this code with my code.

Comment: try logging the value of `url` after the split

Comment: @Farhat After changes i deployed same error is came

Comment: @hana_wujira i didn't get you what logging?

Comment: try to log the value of url before split and check value is getting correctly or not.

Comment: `console.log(url)` to see what the value of `url` is

Comment: yeah iam getting value here correctly  and iam getting  assets/api_urls.json

Comment: @hana_wujira,@Farhat any othere solution ?

Comment: _when i deployed my project i am getting error of this_ the error only happen when it is deployed ?

Comment: yes it happen only when i deployed and i deployed in amazon s3